# Why does the function getcommentcount of facebook4j return null

Tags: facebook4j

I'm using facebook4j to get the Number of replies of a comment but, actually, it returns null whatever the id_comment is
Here is the code that i'm using to get the comment ; i have the ids in an excel file

```
enter code herepublic class RecuperationFacebook {
public static String appId = "appId";
public static String appSecret = "appSecret";
public static String access_token = "";
public static Facebook facebook ;
public RecuperationFacebook()
{
    facebook = new FacebookFactory().getInstance();
    facebook.setOAuthAppId(appId, appSecret);
    facebook.setOAuthAccessToken(new AccessToken(access_token));
}
public static Comment Commentaire(String id_comment) throws FacebookException
{
          Comment commentaire =facebook.getComment(id_comment, null);
          commentaire.getFrom().getId();
          return(commentaire);

}
```

}
//and here is how i'm using the function

```
Comment commentaire = facebook.Commentaire(id_comment);
        Integer Nb_reponse = commentaire.getCommentCount();
        System.out.println("Nb_reponse"+Nb_reponse);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment count is a non-default field so you need to explicitly tell the Facebook API to include it in the response. You can use the [Reading class](https://facebook4j.github.io/javadoc/facebook4j/Reading.html) to achieve this:

```
Reading reading = new Reading().fields("comment_count");
facebook.getComment(commentId, reading);
```

You can find out more in facebook4j's official [documentation](https://facebook4j.github.io/en/code-examples.html#reading).